# Explicitly lock and unlock a table using ODBC

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have to perform some calculations with data stored in an MSSQL Server database and then save the results in the same database.

I need to load (part of) a table into C++ data structures, perform a calculation (that can take substantial time), and finally add some rows to the same table.

The problem is that several users can access the database concurrently, and I want the table to be locked since the data is loaded in memory until the results of the calculation are written to the table.

Using the ODBC SDK, is it possible to explicitly lock and unlock part of a table?

I have tried the following test program, but unfortunately the `INSERT` statement succeeds before `StmtHandle1` is freed:

```
SQLDriverConnect(ConHandle1,  NULL, (SQLCHAR *)"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                                               "SERVER=MyServer;"
                                               "DATABASE=MyDatabase;"/*, ... */);

SQLSetStmtAttr(StmtHandle1,SQL_ATTR_CONCURRENCY,(SQLPOINTER)SQL_CONCUR_LOCK,SQL_IS_INTEGER);

SQLExecDirect(StmtHandle1, (SQLCHAR *)"SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)", SQL_NTS);


SQLDriverConnect(ConHandle2, NULL, (SQLCHAR *)"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                                              "SERVER=MyServer;"
                                              "DATABASE=MyDatabase;"/*, ... */);

SQLSetStmtAttr(StmtHandle2,SQL_ATTR_CONCURRENCY,(SQLPOINTER)SQL_CONCUR_LOCK,SQL_IS_INTEGER);

SQLExecDirect(StmtHandle2, (SQLCHAR *)"INSERT INTO [MyTable] VALUES (...)", SQL_NTS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unfortunately the INSERT statement succeeds before StmtHandle1 is
>   freed

By default SQL Server opereates in autocommit mode, i.e. opens a tarnsaction and commits it for you.

You requested `TABLOCKX` and the table was locked for the duration of your transaction, but what you want instead is to explicitely open a transaction and don't `commit`/`rollback` it until you'll done with your calculations, i.e. you should use

```
begin tran; SELECT top 1 * FROM [MyTable] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK);
```

And you don't need to read the whole table, `top 1 *` is sufficient.

Comment: It does lock the table, but when I try to unlock the table by committing the transaction (i.e. `SQLExecDirect(StmtHandle1, (SQLCHAR *)"COMMIT TRANSACTION", SQL_NTS);`) I get the error "invalid cursor state"

Comment: "invalid cursor state" is not server error, it's smth related to C++. If you cannot execute nothing from that session just kill it, all the locks will be released

Comment: OK. It works fine. I had to set the autocommit mode to off for the current connection: `SQLSetConnectAttr(ConHandle, SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, NULL);`, and then commit the transaction with `SQLEndTran(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ConHandle, SQL_COMMIT);`